# Enterprise Architect (EA) not recognizing TFS workspace

Tags: tfs, enterprise-architect

I'm having some trouble while mapping an EA project to a TFS workspace.

I have connected to a TFS project and pulled some EA project files to a local folder. I can check-in/out files without a problem from Visual Studio.
In the Version control settings in EA, I've set the working copy path to a TFS workspace folder.

For some I get the  following error when I select the folder with the EAB file in it as the TFS workspace;

```
Error while initializing Version Control provider: 
The working copy path ... is not mapped to a TFS workspace
```

If I select a parent folder I get another mapping related error.

I'm using EA v13.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug in EA. Using regional characters in mapped folder name creates this problem.