# Enterprise Architect (EA) - can't save TFS configuration

Tags: tfs, enterprise-architect

I have a TFS shared project that works for everyone except a single person. The only differing factor is the person's name contains Turkish characters like ş and ç.

When that name is written to the *Display Name* area in Version Control Settings (and we have to write it exactly), we get the exact same error as the below link and the special characters change to some other symbol.

Previously, folder names containing Turkish characters were a problem.
[Enterprise Architect (EA) not recognizing TFS workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719840/enterprise-architect-ea-not-recognizing-tfs-workspace)

I'm using EA v13.

Comment: Bravo Geert Bellekens and Daniel Mann for your diligent observation, marking the question as duplicate with the link I gave but if you had read the question in the link, you would see the folder name is the problem and the solution I found was a workaround. This time, the display Name is the problem. EA specifically asks for the name to be written with ş and ç but we cant. It's not some folder name we can change at will and skirt around the problem.